# Difference between executing .bat file and entering the command manually

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, h2

I'm using the H2 database for quite a time with Windows 10 (earlier 7). In the `C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin` folder I have a `h2.bat` with the following first line

> @java -cp "h2-1.3.176.jar;%H2DRIVERS%;%CLASSPATH%" org.h2.tools.Console %*

When I execute this file H2 starts as wanted. Now I tried to open the Windows command window. When I enter there the same line and press return I get as result

```
Starts the H2 Console (web-) server, as well as the TCP and PG server.
Usage: java org.h2.tools.Console <options>
When running without options, -tcp, -web, -browser and -pg are started.
Options are case sensitive. Supported options are:
[-help] or [-?]  Print the list of options
[-url]           Start a browser and connect to this URL
[-driver]        Used together with -url: the driver
[-user]          Used together with -url: the user name
[-password]      Used together with -url: the password
[-web]           Start the web server with the H2 Console
[-tool]          Start the icon or window that allows to start a browser
[-browser]       Start a browser connecting to the web server
[-tcp]           Start the TCP server
[-pg]            Start the PG server
For each Server, additional options are available;
 for details, see the Server tool.
If a service can not be started, the program
 terminates with an exit code of 1.
See also http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Console.html
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: "%*" [50100-176]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
        at org.h2.util.Tool.throwUnsupportedOption(Tool.java:69)
        at org.h2.util.Tool.showUsageAndThrowUnsupportedOption(Tool.java:58)
        at org.h2.tools.Console.runTool(Console.java:205)
        at org.h2.tools.Console.main(Console.java:100)
```

So you see that I get a java exception. Can you explain me why it works by executing the `.bat` file and what to change to be able to execute it manually? I don't see the difference. By the way: Of course I first browsed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin` in the command window.

Comment: %* means the rest of the params, which won't work outside a batch file. Just like the error message indicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@java -cp "h2-1.3.176.jar;%H2DRIVERS%;%CLASSPATH%" org.h2.tools.Console %*
```

The `%*` at the end means "all the params given to this bat file".

so if you called

```
h2.bat param1 param2
```

then the following would be called

```
@java -cp "h2-1.3.176.jar;%H2DRIVERS%;%CLASSPATH%" org.h2.tools.Console param1 param2
```

However when running without a bat file the string `%*` is passed directly to the application. `%*` is not one of the supported options of `org.h2.tools.Console`.